# HTTP methods handling

Tags: http, web, jsf, request

How to implement HTTP method handling for this in jsf build web application:- an application MUST generate an error if an HTTP method used to access a resource is different from that expected. For example, if a module is designed to process HTTP POST requests, and an HTTP GET request is received, the application MUST treat this as an error

Comment: Show the code you have.

Comment: Can you reformat your question? A whole block of text without space is hard to read.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for you response.
I tried managing to handle it by implementing Filters in my java class and defining my methods inside the doFilter method for handling the incoming methods.
The defined Filter is then configured in the web.xml.